# Transfer content from one tab to another without browser extension possible?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome browser tab with a textarea filled with some ASCII content. I want to open a new tab, load a special URL, where is a HTML document with an empty textarea, and transfer content from the textarea in the first tab to the textarea in the second, newly opened tab.

My question: Is it possible without a browser extension?

**Edit**: all data are placed in the same domain and server, both are mine, like this:

- First tab is located under https://tab1.my.domain.com
- Second tab is located under https://tab2.my.domain.com

phpinfo:
[image]

Comment: Are the tabs on the same domain? If so: local storage / cookies, if not: probably no way, no.

Comment: You can simulate it with the help of web sockets. But in this way, the data goes through your server and comes back to the other tab.

Comment: @luk2302 I added an update to my post.

Comment: @Eldar both tabs are located on my server - I updated my post.

Comment: In that case local storage and / or cookies should work without much trouble, just need to set the domain to my.domain.com

Comment: What language / system are you working with.

Comment: @MasonStedman both tabs are HTML with a little bit of JS. Server nginx.

Comment: More accurately what is the core (ie php, node, etc). So I can give you a code example.  Subdomain CORS requests are a weird kinda stupid for most stuff

Comment: @MasonStedman thank you! PHP is 7.4.15. The whole phpinfo I've added to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for PHP you both need to make your settings wildcards (or w\e permissions you want)  Vs standard init sessions (applies to cookies too) to allow domains to access other subdomains cookies.

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com', true);
session_start();
```

Also for any JS ajax request you'll need to enable xhr credentials / cross domain.

```
            $.ajax({
                type: method,
                url:  url,
                data: request,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                traditional: true,
                crossDomain: true,
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    ...
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, thrown) {
                    ...
                }
            });
```

Neither PHP or JS natively "like" CORS requests these days, even from the same subdomains.  They have to be explicitly enabled.